# feature-requests for the blog: OpenID and threading for comments

Tags: feature-request, support, blog

I. [OpenId](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/openid/), [OpenId commenting](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/comments-with-openid/).

This is requested by users. It would allow them to comment using the same OpenID they are using for SE.

II. Support for threaded commenting.

Comment threading makes discussions much more readable. As an example see [Dick Lipton's blog](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/). Without threading the discussions in comments will become completely incomprehensible. The checkbox for threaded commenting is already checked but it does not work. I am guessing this has to do with theme but I am not sure.

III. [mcrypt](http://us3.php.net/mcrypt) module on the blog (for hiding emails addresses with reCHAPTCHA).

When I try to enable the reCHAPTCHA for hiding emails it give an error that the module is missing. This will hide the email address of people in the posts from spam bots by requiring the reader to pass reCHAPTCHA to see email addresses.

Comment: I strongly support the request for threaded commenting.  I tried to respond to two comments by two separate commenters, and ended up producing something that could be hard to read -- more so, if multiple people were having a technical discussion.

Comment: Yes, I agree. These features would certainly be handy.

Comment: Why do you need openid commenting?  We don't require users to register to comment...

Comment: @Rebecca: "This would enable those of us who use OpenID to login to stackexchange.com to use _the same ID_ on the blog." (emphasis added by me) Maybe not essential, but would be useful for people who use OpenID for commenting on blogs in general.

Comment: @RebeccaChernof: one more thing. In the past popular TCS blogs have had problems with anonymous commentators. I think we may want to restrict the commentators to those with OpenIDs to avoid similar problems and then approve the first time commentators to play it safe (it seems that we can set the preferences such that after approval of the first comment the later comments by the same user do not need approval).

Comment: Let's not mince words here. @Rebecca Chernoff: when Kaveh says "problems," he means things like "multiple legally actionable threats of sexual assault against a female colleague because she was offered a prestigious job." I have no position about Open IDs. However, there does need to be comment moderation. I would prefer it if every commenter needs to be manually approved the first time.  This is not optional for me.  If there is no comment moderation on the blog, I will resign as co-editor

Comment: @AaronSterling: there is an option similar to one on Lipton's blog, i.e. first time comments should be approved (there is also the option of completely moderating comments, i.e. all comments would need approval). Its checkbox is not checked right now but we can enable it. (However without OpenID it will be based only on the name and email address entered by the user.) ps: enabled, please check to see if it works.

Comment: Great, thank you @Kaveh.

Comment: If you want moderation, fine, use it.  (:  But please don't use the email notifications on comments, because that would email all of the admins on the blog, including the SE staff.

Comment: I also support comment threading

Comment: @SureshVenkat: working on it...it isn't a minor change.

Comment: I just looked, and I don't think my dashboard has access to moderation level changes.  Kaveh and @Suresh, could one of you please turn off email notifications, as Rebecca said?

Comment: @AaronSterling: I think it is already off.

Comment: I think I was the one who first asked for OpenID. What I should have asked for are the same login options as stackexchange has so anybody can use the same ID (if they want to).

Answer (score 3):

Threaded comments have been added to the blog.

I am looking at options for using openid.  Both the plugins linked in the question (and others I've found) are not compatible with the latest versions of WordPress.  I'm still looking for something that will work.

Comment: Awesome. ${}$ :)

Comment: Thanks for all your hard work Rebecca.